# Page overflowing to the right when I use center an image container

Tags: css, flexbox, text-align

I'm a little stuck with this problem: I have a nested image container that contains three images per row, three rows. I need it to be centered. I tried text-align on the parent container but it doesn't work so I used flex property `align-items: center;` but instead of aligning itself on the center of the page, the image container overflows to the right making it scrollable.

I've tried inspecting the page in Google Chrome but I can't seem to find what element was causing it. Here is a snapshot with the align property unchecked:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSala.png)

Here is what happens when I tick it:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnyLY.png)

Here is also my code in Codepen if you need to check it out:

https://codepen.io/asparagus-inator/pen/dyOrNmv

I've been looking at my code for hours now and I'm at a loss as to what causes this behavior. I would really appreciate the help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `margin: 0 auto` on `.gallery-images`? I prefer to use CSS grid for photo galleries myself. Using images with flexbox can sometimes create some unexpected behavior, especially when using Safari.

Comment: The image container still overflows to the right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the img elements. Changing the img-row and gallery-img classes fix it. Just needed to set the width properly and justify the img-row content.

```
.img-row {
     display: flex;
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     justify-content: center;
 }

 .gallery-img {
     width: 30%;
     height: auto;
     padding: 1%;
}
```